# How to make some space on iPad?

Tags: ipad, memory

Is there a way to delete music, podcast or iTunes-U to make some space available (to take more pictures for instance) without a computer ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this without a computer? You need to sync your iPad to iTunes on a Windows PC or Mac **each day** in order for it to work correctly. Once you have synced your data, you can choose what to move to the Mac or PC and what to keep on the iPad. Trying to delete files on the iPad without syncing is dangerous because you won't be able to get anything back if you delete it and then change your mind.

Comment: To clarify, it is not necessary to sync an iPad each day.

Comment: No, it's not necessary to sync the iPad each day, but this person seems to want to use his iPad without syncing it at all, and that is unwise.

Comment: @wheat Its hard to tell from the question, but my guess is that Rabskatran is thinking of being away from the computer, wanting to take a picture and not having any more space.  In this case it makes perfect sense to want to delete something that can be synced again later.

Comment: I'm just always paranoid about backing up data.

Comment: Yes, I left for holydays for 3 weeks. And I didn't notice that I've not much space left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete videos from the Videos app by tapping and holding on the thumbnail, then pressing the red X that appears in the corner (just like deleting apps from your home screen).

To delete audio podcasts, find them in the Music app, swipe your finger across the name of the podcast (or episode) and press the delete button. (The same way you would with emails.)